# Is saying a specific person, for example hitler will go to hell incorrect?

Tags: hadith, jahannam

There are multiple answers on this site informing that person X fate is with Allah, we shouldnt tell he's going to hell if he's a disbeliever.

Is saying a specific person, for example adolf hitler will go to hell incorrect?

Provided theres a hadith to give dead disbelievers glad tidings of hell.

https://abdurrahman.org/category/islam/dealings-with-non-muslims/

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38699/22

Comment: lol @ "glad tidings" of hell ... may Allah protect us all from the HellFire. Amen.

Comment: @Ahmed, https://islamqa.info/en/221739

Comment: @Praveenladak Please elaborate. I didn't get how the link is connected to my comment or your question in general?

Answer (score 5):

A person who dies on disbelief will enter hell-fire, and will not be forgiven.

> إن الله لا يغفر أن يشرك به
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive *shirk* with Him
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48)</sup>
>
> إن الذين كفروا وصدوا عن سبيل الله ثم ماتوا وهم كفار فلن يغفر الله لهم
>
> Indeed, those who disbelieved and averted [people] from the path of Allah and then died while they were disbelievers - never will Allah forgive them
>
> <sup>— [Quran 47:34](https://quran.com/47/34)</sup>
>
> إن تستغفر لهم سبعين مرة فلن يغفر الله لهم ذلك بأنهم كفروا بالله ورسوله
>
> If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times - never will Allah forgive them. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and His Messenger.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:80](https://quran.com/9/80)</sup>
>
> وعد الله ... الكفار نار جهنم
>
> Allah has promised ...  the disbelievers the fire of Hell
>
> <sup>—[Quran 9:68](https://quran.com/9/68)</sup>

The issue is that you can not know for ***certain*** whether a specific individual actually died on disbelief.

Maybe the person was a believer in secret and was forced to hide his religion:

> إلا من أكره وقلبه مطمئن بالإيمان
>
> except for one who is forced while his heart is secure in faith
>
> <sup>—[Quran 16:106](https://quran.com/16/106)</sup>

Maybe he repented and accepted Islam shortly before death and you don't know about it, but Allah knows about it.

> إني أعلم ما لا تعلمون
>
> Indeed, I know that which you do not know.
>
> <sup>—[Quran 2:30](https://quran.com/2/30)</sup>
>
> فإنه يعلم السر وأخفى
>
> He knows the secret and what is [even] more hidden
>
> <sup>—[Quran 20:7](https://quran.com/20/7)</sup>

Maybe he didn't receive Islam's message and so his judgement is currently suspended:

> وما كنا معذبين حتى نبعث رسولا
>
> And never would We punish until We sent a messenger
>
> <sup>—[Quran 17:15](https://quran.com/17/15); see [What is the fate of someone who died never having heard of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/)</sup>

If it was any of these cases and the person was a believer and you went ahead and declared that he is a dweller of hell, then that would be wrong.

---

<sub>For legal purposes like funeral, inheritance etc. the person will be treated according to his apparent condition.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=331456) quotes multiple scholars who say declaring a specific individual will certainly go to hell is forbidden, except if this individual is mentioned in the Qur'an or hadith.

One example is: [Qur'an 111:1-3](https://quran.com/111/1-3) says [Abu Lahab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab%C5%AB_Lahab) will go to hell.  So we can say he will go to hell.

Who goes to hell is ultimately up to Allah, and He may make exceptions:

> And [mention, O Muhammad], the Day when He will gather them together [and say], "O company of jinn, you have [misled] many of mankind." And their allies among mankind will say, "Our Lord, some of us made use of others, and we have [now] reached our term, which you appointed for us." He will say, **"The Fire is your residence, wherein you will abide eternally, except for what Allah wills. Indeed, your Lord is Wise and Knowing."**
>   <sub>[Qur'an 6:128](https://quran.com/6/128)</sub>

We know that *Allah forgives all sins* ([Qur'an 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53)), and we don't have Allah's infallible judgment and unlimited knowledge: we don't know who He does and doesn't forgive.  We could be wrong.